# AngularJS my custom directive can't access attributes yet it appears other custom directives can

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following template for a custom directive.

```
    .directive('myDirective', ['$controller',function($controller) {
      return {
            templateUrl: 'client/test.ng.html',
            scope: true,
            controller: ['$scope','$attrs',function($scope,$attrs){
              console.log($attrs)
          }],
          transclude: true,

      }
    }])
```

This directive is being called as follows

```
    <my-directive view="{{view}}"></my-directive>
    <ion-tab ng-if="platform != 'android'" title="{{label}}"  icon-off="{{off}}" icon-on="{{on}}" href="#/tab/{{view}}"> 
            <my-directive view="{{view}}"></my-directive>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab ng-if="platform == 'android'" title="{{label}}" class="tab-item" href="#/tab/{{view}}">
            <my-directive view="{{view}}"></my-directive>
    </ion-tab>
```

`$attrs.view` is `{{view}}`, uninterpolated.  `<ion-tab>` interpolates the expression to the variable value, displaying the right data.

This is very confusing to me. I've put `my-directive` both inside and outside the `ion-tab` directive just in case there is some kind of scoping issue.

What is the key to accessing the value of expression and using that value to in turn call another directive?

---

Background:

The reason I'm going through all this is because

`<ion-nav-view name="tab-{{view}}"></ion-nav-view>` doesn't work. It, like `my-directive` doesn't seem to be able to get the value for ```view`` but the raw uninterpreted request for it. I'm attempting to get the value and call this directive directly.

I seem to be able to get the value I want with $scope.$parent.view yet mysteriously setting $scope.view = $scope.$parent.view and setting {{view}} in the child template DOESNT work either!?

---

More insight, console.log($attrs) gives:

```
  $…t.Attributes {$attr: Object, $$element: jQuery.fn.init[1], view: "{{view}}", class: "pane tab-content", navView: "active"}
```

Yet when this is expanded we have

```
   $$element: jQuery.fn.init[1]
     $$observers: Object
     $attr: Object
     class: "pane tab-content"
     navView: "active"
     view: "dash"
     __proto__: Object
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the script where "view"  value is fetch? This script is look fine. $scope.$parent.view is work because you set scope : true when defining your directive. So, the directive prototypically inherits the parent scope

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Sure thing, here is a related problem in more detail w/plunker link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854373/angularjs-cannot-interpolate-attribute-from-first-directive-to-a-second-w-pl

Comment: I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854373/angularjs-cannot-interpolate-attribute-from-first-directive-to-a-second-w-pl/30859861#30859861 .  Here is the final fiddle .http://plnkr.co/edit/WoglpCyQmg9WYs5MrKYw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use link function to get attributes values.

```
.directive('myDirective', ['$controller',function($controller) {
  return {
        templateUrl: 'client/test.ng.html',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
          console.log(attrs);
        }
   }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. After some digging around it seems that the template function is called before the link (pre and post) so I'm not sure how to influence the template's render since it is already evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I cann't see any HTML inside your directive, so I removed transclude: true

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'client/test.ng.html',
        scope: {
            view: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log("view", view);
            scope.$watch("view", function (newView, prevView) {
                console.log("changed view", scope.view, newView, prevView);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a *timing issue* and is related to when certain things happen inside a directive's lifecycle and the several phases it gets throught.
In as little detaila as possible, these are the phases:

1. Compiling
2. Instantiating the controller
3. Pre-linking
4. Post-linking

Note that resovling interpolated attributes (`{{...}}`) to values happens sometime during the pre-linking phase (and it is also an Angular built-in directive that does that). What this means is that:

a. The values are **not** resolved during controller instantiation.
b. The values are certainly resolved during the post-linking phase.
c. The values may or may not be resolved during the pre-linking phase, based on the relative priority of your directive vs the (esoteric) attribute interpolation directive (which has priorirty 100).

<sub>Note: A higher priority means the pre-linking is happening sooner.</sub>

---

The [docs on `$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) do a fair job explaining what is going on (if you read it really carefully).

Comment: How can the pre-link function inject data into the template if the template function is called before the pre-link?

Comment: I rethought out this question and included a plunker demo in case you might be curious to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854373/angularjs-cannot-interpolate-attribute-from-first-directive-to-a-second-w-pl

Comment: @Babak: The template is determined (either using an inline template or resolving a template or calling a template function) and it is then used for creating an element (with children etc). Then the interpolate directive will change the created element's attributes' values during the pre-linking phase (meaning that before that the elements has `some-attr="{{textWithCurlies}}"` and after that the elements has `some-attr="a very meaningful value"`).

Comment: @Babak: I had this comment written up but never pushed the `Add Comment` button, so I am posting it anyway. I will take a look into that question.